# Map two colour aesthetics for different factors in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to use ggplot to make a simple field map. The field design is in a format like this:

```
design <- data.frame(Genotype=rep(LETTERS[1:4], 4), Status=rep(c("P","N"), each=8),
                 Density=rep(c(40,80), each=4),
                 Row=rep(seq(1:4)),
                 Range=rep(1:4, each=4))
```

I want a map with fill mapped to `Genotype` and something else (ideally luminance) mapped to `Density`. The closest I've come is to use `alpha`, but it's not ideal, since it goes from very low alpha to very high. At very low alpha it's hard to see what the fill is.

Here's the code for my plot at present:

```
d.p <- ggplot(design, aes(Row, Range))
d.p1 <- d.p + geom_tile(aes(fill=Genotype, alpha=Density))
```

I've fiddled around with `scale_fill_hue` but can't seem to make anything sensible happen.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

I'm sorry I realised I left out a fundamental aspect of my real world problem when I made the reproducible example, fixed above.

As is pointed out below, `alpha` can be mapped to Density, but I also need to distinguish between `Status`. Hatching seems an obvious solution, but I understand that is not an option. I could manually assign similar colour (light blue, dark blue etc), but I would really like to be able to automate this so that I can do it for any field design.

Any ideas appreciated, and sorry for the confusion!

Answer (score 4):

I will ignore the fact that `Row` and `Genotype` contain redundant information, and offer up this:

```
ggplot(design,aes(x = Row,y = Range)) + 
    geom_tile(fill = "transparent",colour = "black") +
    geom_point(aes(colour = Genotype,size = factor(Density),shape = Status)) + 
    scale_size_manual(values = c(3,6))
```

[image]

But something tells me there will be a reason you can't do this either.

Comment: I can totally see where you're coming from, and this is a perfectly reasonable solution in a plot. The problem here is I'm not really making a plot, I'm making a map, and field maps have a defined style. While `Genotype` and `Row` have redundant information in this case, that will usually not be the case. I think the only real solution is manually apply colours that are similar, then use alpha like you suggested earlier. But you've got me along the way.