# Mapping an aesthetic using ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

All,
I am beginner to ggplot, and struggling with it. So, I bought Wickham's book. I don't understand the difference between these three code snippets:

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
geom_point(aes(colour = "green"))
```

vs.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
geom_point(aes(colour = 1))
```

vs.

```
ggplot(mpg, aes(cty, hwy)) +
geom_point(aes(colour = "1"))
```

While I see the output, and the legend says "green" in one case and 1 in the other, but if we are really mapping an aesthetic to a variable, we should see the default pink color for all three, but this doesn't happen for the second item. Why is this? I'd appreciate any thoughts.

Comment: Compare `colour = 1` versus `colour = factor(1)`.

Comment: Categorial (discrete) vs continuous color scales. Characters == categorical/discrete (they get converted to factors). Numbers are continuous (gradient).

Answer (score 1):

The second example provides a *numerical* value of 1 for the "colour" aesthetic ("color" would work just as well, by the way). Because a numerical value is provided, `ggplot` assumes that a numerical color scale should be used. The default numerical color scale is a gradient that runs from bright blue to black. The default categorical scale, which is triggered by the first and third examples, is a rainbow scale with hue spacing equal to the number of levels in the provided variable.

Comment: Thanks Jdobres. That helps. However, then I looked at the scale used by ggplot at the following link: http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_gradient.html. I chose decimal  (1256259) for the Hex 132B43 in example #2 above i.e. colour = 1256259. However, this just changed the label. How do I see the change in the gradient? My hypothesis that by changing the number, the gradient would change turned out to be false. So, I am definitely missing some major concept. I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: @watchtower Mapping a constant value `color = CONSTANT` will only ever result in one of the default color schemes (absent other modifications). ggplot will essentially interpret that as a "new constant column" in your data frame and will simply use whichever default scale is appropriate for the data type.

Comment: If you want to change the actual colors displayed in the scale, you need the various `scale` functions, such as `scale_color_gradient()`. The aesthetic declarations in `aes()` simply tell ggplot which columns of data should be used for which attributes.

Comment: Thanks for excellent responses jdobres and joran. I wish I could give you 5000 points. I did a bit of research on this to find out how I can know the default color scheme at http://docs.ggplot2.org/0.9.3.1/scale_gradient.html. It seems the default color palette for gradient is dark blue. Is there anyway I can find this out--i..e what's the default color palette? I think the default color palette for discrete variable is at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10809166/map-two-colour-aesthetics-for-different-factors-in-ggplot2?rq=1 I'd appreciate your thoughts.